# New component in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I want to create a new element to use in a circuit diagram. So far I have used CircuiTikz for the circuit diagram, but I am not familiar with the low level PGF commands that defines the standard elements. What would be the easiest way to create a simple component like the one I have drawn in the figure? I must be able to include it in the rest of my circuit diagram though.

[image: component]

Code for the circuit I want to connect the new element to:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.75, american inductors, american voltages, european resistors]
        \draw
        (0,3.5) to[short] (0.5,4) to[short] (1,4) to[L] (3,4) to[short] (6,4)
        (0,3.5) to[short] (0.5,3.5) to[short] (1,3.5) to[L] (3,3.5) to[short] (6,3.5)
        (0,3.5) to[short] (0.5,3) to[short] (1,3) to[L] (3,3) to[short] (6,3);

        \draw
        (0,3.5) to[short, *-] (0,2)
        to[R] (0,0)
        node[ground] {};
        %I want to connect the new component here at the red dot!
        \filldraw[fill=red] (0,2.5) circle (0.2);

    \end{circuitikz}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

I want to connect it at the red dot.

Comment: Welcome! Could you post a small, sample diagram with the code you use? Since you need the answer to be usable in that context, people need to see that context in order to think about a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. Could you make it compile, too? Especially for TikZ, you often need libraries and things to get it working, and it is hard to keep track of what is needed for what. (Also, it makes it easier for people to answer if they can copy-paste-compile a document and just work on answering the question.)

Comment: I have some tutorials on the subject on my web side http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm

Comment: I added the compiled figure.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Many thanks for the CircuiTikz tutorials.

Comment: @sergej - You're welcome.  Actually, I was going to work on this myself and forgot.  Well, that and never having seen anything like it before.

Comment: @Eirik What kind of component is it actually?

Answer (score 6):

Something like this? It is based on [John Kormylo's bipole tutorial](http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/bipole.pdf):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
% used to process styles for to-path
\def\TikzBipolePath#1#2{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{#1}{#2}}
% restore size value for bipole definitions
\pgf@circ@Rlen = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
\makeatother
\newlength{\ResUp}
\newlength{\ResDown}
\newlength{\ResLeft}
\newlength{\ResRight}

% newcomponent
\ctikzset{bipoles/newcomponent/height/.initial=.50}   % box height
\ctikzset{bipoles/newcomponent/width/.initial=.50}    % box width
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}                               % no extra anchors
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/newcomponent/height}}
{newcomponent}                                        % component name
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/newcomponent/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/newcomponent/width}}
{                                                     % component symbol drawing...
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
  \pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}                    % coordinates
  \pgfextracty{\ResDown}{\southwest}
  \pgfextractx{\ResLeft}{\southwest}
  \pgfextractx{\ResRight}{\northeast}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\ResDown}{\ResRight}}      % two arc's
  \pgfpatharc{90}{-90}{\ResRight/2}
  \pgfpatharc{90}{-90}{\ResRight/2}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\ResUp}{\ResLeft}}         % another two arc's
  \pgfpatharc{90}{-90}{\ResLeft/2}
  \pgfpatharc{90}{-90}{\ResLeft/2}
  \pgfusepath{draw}                                   % draw it!
}
\def\circlepath#1{\TikzBipolePath{newcomponent}{#1}}
\tikzset{newcomponent/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\circlepath, l=#1}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.75, american inductors, american voltages, european resistors]
        \draw
        (0,3.5) to[short] (0.5,4) to[short] (1,4) to[L] (3,4) to[short] (6,4)
        (0,3.5) to[short] (0.5,3.5) to[short] (1,3.5) to[L] (3,3.5) to[short] (6,3.5)
        (0,3.5) to[short] (0.5,3) to[short] (1,3) to[L] (3,3) to[short] (6,3);

        \draw
        (0,3.5) to[short, *-] (0,2)
        to[newcomponent] (0,0)                       % connect the new component
        to[R] (0,-2)
        node[ground] {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```