# How to move anchors in new circuitikz component?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, pgfkeys

There are some components missing in the nice circuitikz package. I tried to create these with help of the answers to questions [CircuiTikZ — create new component](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19204/circuitikz-create-new-component) and [New component in circuitikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240260/new-component-in-circuitikz).
Now I get following result for a so called norator. As one can see, the connectors are in the center of the circles. I want them at the left and right sides of the circles.
Any recommendations are very welcome.

Many thanks in advance

[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
% used to process styles for to-path
\def\TikzBipolePath#1#2{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{#1}{#2}}
    % restore size value for bipole definitions
\pgf@circ@Rlen = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
\makeatother

\newlength{\ResUp}
\newlength{\ResDown}
\newlength{\ResLeft}
\newlength{\ResRight}

% norator
\ctikzset{bipoles/norator/height/.initial=.35}   % box height
\ctikzset{bipoles/norator/width/.initial=.35}    % box width
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}                           % no extra anchors
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/norator/height}}
{norator}                                        % component name
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/norator/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/norator/width}}
{                                                 % component symbol drawing ...
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
  \pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}                % coordinates
  \pgfextracty{\ResDown}{\southwest}
  \pgfextractx{\ResLeft}{\southwest}
  \pgfextractx{\ResRight}{\northeast}
  \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{\ResUp}{0}}
        {\pgfpoint{0}{\ResUp}}
        {\pgfpoint{\ResUp}{0}}
  \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{-\ResUp}{0}}
        {\pgfpoint{0}{\ResUp}}
        {\pgfpoint{\ResUp}{0}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}                               % draw it!
}

\def\circlepath#1{\TikzBipolePath{norator}{#1}}
\tikzset{norator/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\circlepath, l=#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.75, european resistors]
    \draw
    (0,0) to [short, o-] (1,0)
    to [norator] (2,0)                       % connect the new component
    to [R, -o] (5,0)
    ;

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some experiments, finally I got some solution:

[image]

The values, which I modified are initial height and width and then the
centers of the circles and radius.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
% used to process styles for to-path
\def\TikzBipolePath#1#2{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{#1}{#2}}
    % restore size value for bipole definitions
\pgf@circ@Rlen = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
\makeatother

\newlength{\ResUp}
\newlength{\ResDown}
\newlength{\ResLeft}
\newlength{\ResRight}

% norator
\ctikzset{bipoles/norator/height/.initial=.5}   % box height
\ctikzset{bipoles/norator/width/.initial=.5}    % box width
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}                           % no extra anchors
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/norator/height}}
{norator}                                        % component name
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/norator/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/norator/width}}
{                                                 % component symbol drawing ...
  \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}    \pgfstartlinewidth}
  \pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}                % coordinates
  \pgfextracty{\ResDown}{\southwest}
  \pgfextractx{\ResLeft}{\southwest}
  \pgfextractx{\ResRight}{\northeast}
  \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{\ResUp/2}{0}}
        {\pgfpoint{0}{\ResUp/2}}
        {\pgfpoint{\ResUp/2}{0}}
  \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{-\ResUp/2}{0}}
        {\pgfpoint{0}{\ResUp/2}}
        {\pgfpoint{\ResUp/2}{0}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}                               % draw it!
}

\def\circlepath#1{\TikzBipolePath{norator}{#1}}
\tikzset{norator/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\circlepath, l=#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.75, european resistors]
    \draw
    (0,0) to [short, o-] (1,0)
    to [norator] (2,0)                       % connect the new component
    to [R, -o] (5,0)
    ;

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-circ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[dimen = m](5.5,1)
  \pnodes(0,0.5){A}(1,0.5){B}(2,0.5){C}(3,0.5){D}(5.5,0.5){E}
  \wire[arrows = o-](A)(B)
  \Ucc(B)(C){}
  \Ucc(C)(D){}
  \resistor[arrows = -o](D)(E){}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Well, yes, but I fear that I can't integrate this into a larger circuit picture in combination with other cicuitikz components. But thanks anyhow.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein You could still consider accepting the answer in order to "close" the question.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint I accept the answer and close the question. [close].